# Cargo deployment to Glassfish3.x

Tags: glassfish, gradle, cargo

Is there anyway with Cargo deployment to deploy to a specific Glassfish virtual Server?  I am using Gradle and all works welland deploys... but I have about 10 virtual servers under my GF domain and my application gets deployed to all of them........ Even though I have tried specifying a port.

I have tried:

gradlew cargoRedeployRemote -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=xx.xxx.xx.xx -Dcargo.servlet.port=8082

but this doesn't seem to do anything special (it is a Spring MVC war that I am deploying)

Am I missing something?

Comment: These system properties are not evaluated from the command line. You'd probably have to set them with the help of the plugin's DSL or as task property values.

Comment: Ben, on a slightly different topic.... Did you take the 0.3 plugin down?  I use to have this in my script:      buildscript {
 repositories {
  add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
   name = 'GitHub'
   addArtifactPattern 'http://cloud.github.com/downloads/[organisation]/[module]/[module]-[revision].[ext]'
  }
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath 'bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:0.3'
  
  
 }
}   --- However this gets a 407 error now. I've upgraded to the 1.4 plugin, but it doesn't seem to extend "war" any longer -- so I have to do a build-then a cargoredeployremote

Comment: GitHub took down their download section. That's why you can't access it anymore. The FAQ explains how to create a task dependency on the `war` task and why it was taken out. I don't think the plugin ever applied the WAR plugin directly.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin.  I added the statement --"cargoRedeployRemote.dependsOn war" and when I click on cargoRedeployRemote in the gradle tasks, my projects build and deploy nicely.  Great plugin!